# Circumcentre of a triangle given the radius vectors of the vertices

Tags: geometry, vectors

If the radius vectors of the three vertices **A**, **B** and **C** of a triangle **ABC** are $\vec{a}$, $\vec{b}$ and $\vec{c}$ respectively, the radius vector of the circumcenter is given by $\frac{\vec{a}\sin(2A) +\vec{b}\sin(2B)+\vec{c}\sin(2C)}{\sin(2A)+\sin(2B)+\sin(2C)}$.

---

How do we go about proving the above result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We first show a result: For $\triangle ABC$ with circumcenter $O$, $$\vec{OA}\cdot \sin2A+\vec{OB}\cdot \sin2B+\vec{OC}\cdot \sin2C=0$$
This can be proved by extending $AO$ to $A'$, where $A'$ lies on the circle, then drawing $A'B\parallel OC$ and $A'C'\parallel OB$. Notice that $\angle OA'B'=\angle A'OC'=180^\circ - \angle AOC = 180^\circ - 2\angle B$ and $\angle OB'A' = 180^\circ-\angle BOC = 2\angle A$. Hence by the Sine law, $$\frac{OB'}{\sin \angle OA'B'} = \frac{OA'}{\sin \angle OB'A'}= \frac{OB}{\sin \angle OB'A'} \implies \vec{OB'}=\frac{\sin \angle OA'B'}{\sin \angle OB'A'}\cdot \vec{OB}=\frac{\sin 2B}{\sin 2A}\cdot \vec{OB}$$Similarly, we can get $$\vec{OC'}= \frac{\sin 2C}{\sin 2A}\cdot \vec{OC}$$
Now, since $\vec{OB'}+\vec{OC'}=\vec{OA'}=-\vec{OA}$, multiplying both sides by $\sin 2A$ and we get the result.

Back to the original question, we can simply write $\vec{OA} = \vec{a}-\vec{r}$, $\vec{OB} = \vec{b}-\vec{r}$, $\vec{OC} = \vec{c}-\vec{r}$ where $\vec{r}$ is the radius vector of the circumcenter. Then, $$\sum(\vec{a}-\vec{r})\sin 2A =0\implies \vec{r} = \frac{\vec{a}\sin2A+\vec{b}\sin2B+\vec{c}\sin2C}{\sin2A+\sin2B+\sin2C}$$
as desired.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You just need to find the [baricentric coordinates](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BarycentricCoordinates.html) of the circumcenter $O$.
By denoting $AB,AC,BC$ with $c,b,a$ as usual, we have that the distances of $O$ from the sides of $ABC$ are given by $R\cos A,R\cos B,R\cos C$, hence the [trilinear coordinates](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrilinearCoordinates.html) of the circumcenter are given by $O=[\cos A,\cos B,\cos C]$, hence the baricentric coordinates are given by $[\sin A\cos A,\sin B\cos B,\sin C\cos C]=[\sin(2A),\sin(2B),\sin(2C)]$ and

$$\vec{O}=\frac{\sin(2A)\vec{A}+\sin(2B)\vec{B}+\sin(2C)\vec{C}}{\sin(2A)+\sin(2B)+\sin(2C)}$$
follows. You may notice that $R^2\left(\sin(2A)+\sin(2B)+\sin(2C)\right)=2\Delta = \frac{abc}{2R}$, hence
$$ \sin(2A)+\sin(2B)+\sin(2C) = \frac{abc}{2R^3}.$$

Comment: Thankyou for your help. Have a good day.

Comment: This is a really beautiful answer. I never thought of using baricentric coordinates before!